# Overflow error in vb.net while adding data in access databse

Tags: vb.net

I'm getting error Overflow while sending data into my access database my code is here

```
 Try
        Dim sqlconn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim sqlquery As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim connString As String
        connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\NSM.accdb"
        sqlconn.ConnectionString = connString
        sqlquery.Connection = sqlconn
        sqlconn.Open()
        sqlquery.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Student_Information([Roll_Number], [Class], [Section], [First_Name], [Last_Name], [Gender], [Date_Of_Birth], [Category], [Religion], [Cast], [Mobile_Number], [Email], [Admission_Date], [Image], [Father_Name], [Father_Phone], [Father_Occupation], [Mother_Name], [Mother_Phone], [Mother_Occupation])VALUES(@rno, @class, @section, @fname, @lname, @gen, @dob, @cat, @rel, @cast, @mnum, @email, @adate, @img, @fathname, @fathnum, @fathocc, @mname, @mnum, @mocc)"
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rnum", Convert.ToInt64(rnum.Text))
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@class", class1.SelectedItem.ToString)
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@section", section.SelectedItem.ToString)
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", fname.Text)
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", lname.Text)
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gen", gender.SelectedItem.ToString)
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", dob.Value.ToShortDateString)
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cat", cat.SelectedItem.ToString)
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rel", rel.Text)
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cast", cast.Text)
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mnum", Convert.ToInt64(mnum.Text))
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email.Text)
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adate", adate.Value.ToShortDateString)
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", Str)
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fathname", "fname")
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fathnum", 9876543210)
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fathocc", "fathocc")
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mname", "mname")
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mnum", 7894561230)
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mocc", "mocc")
        sqlquery.ExecuteNonQuery()
        sqlconn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

I already checked datatypes and all things but still i'm facing this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fathnum and mnum - Assuming they are long integer.

Long Integer — For integers that range from -2,147,483,648 to +2,147,483,647. Storage requirement is four bytes.  Anything above/below that will cause an overflow.

To store numbers as large as 64 bits you will need to use the DOUBLE or DECIMAL type, or you could use a string.

If you aren't doing mathematical operations on them, you might want to use a string on them.

Reference: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/set-the-field-size-ba65e5a7-2e6f-4737-8e72-36b93f966a33

Comment: from MS Docs Numeric Data Types (Visual Basic) "you can use the Long data type instead. Long variables can hold numbers from -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 through 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. "

Comment: I have think you are confusing VB and Access...click on the link...it's right there

Comment: So sorry, Thanks for straightening me out.

Answer (score 0):

You have a parameter of @rnum that doesnt have `@rnum` in the sql statement, I believe it should be `@rno` ...
Or change `@rno` in SQL to `@rnum` either way they need to match :)

Hth

Chicken